# Content Encoding Error

Tags: php, apache, http, gzip

I have a page with gzip and in my php index file i have ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] has value gzip,deflate and even that i receive in some refresh case that error about Encoding.

In htacces i added php_value zlib.output_compression Off and nothing. Any ideea how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a short time fix but this worked for me, so that I could at least see the site.

Go to "about:config"

In the filter type encoding. Look for “network.http.accept-encoding”

Mine said "gzip, deflate", modify this to say "true"

Answer (score 0):

if your php_value is doing nothing it's likely your PHP install is running in CGI mode (please confirm if not), for php_values to be added in your .htaccess file then PHP needs to be running as an Apache module (DSO). Try using `ini_set` in your code or modifying your php.ini if you have access to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify `network.http.accept-encoding` to `true`, this worked for me.

Comment: This value is set to `gzip, deflate` in my Firefox and changing it to `true` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your gzip compression. Many old systems have settings for this e.g. In the old phpBB2 there is an option "Enable GZip Compression" in your Board admin config page. Set this to "No"